# How to Bind Specific Dates in calender asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list to bind a calender. I have List of Dates. But problem in loading the dates.

Here i tried:

```
void BindCalender() 
    {
        var days = (List<DateTime>)Session["WorkDates"];
        if (days != null)
        {
            foreach (var v in days)
            {
                Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(v);                   
            }                            
        }
    }
```

This will add the dates to the calendar1
but how can i disable all others dates expect these list days?

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, assume you have a calendar named cal that is written like:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="cal" runat="server" OnDayRender="cal_DayRender" />
```

Then you can write a DayRender EventHandler similar to the method below to handle nonselectable/excluded dates, add strikeouts and different BackColors to make it obvious in the UI, etc.

```
   protected void cal_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            var days = (List<DateTime>)Session["WorkDates"];

            if (!days.Contains(e.Day.Date))
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                e.Cell.Font.Strikeout = true;
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Chartreuse;
            }

        }
```